# Machine Learning Model Only Predicting Mode in Data Set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to do sentiment analysis for text. I have 909 phrases commonly used in emails, and I scored them out of ten for how angry they are, when isolated.

Now, I upload this .csv file to a Jupyter Notebook, where I import the following modules:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
```

Now, I define both columns as 'phrases' and 'anger':

```
df=pd.read_csv('Book14.csv', names=['Phrase', 'Anger'])
df_x = df['Phrase']
df_y = df['Anger']
```

Subsequently, I split this data such that 20% is used for testing and 80% is used for training:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_x, df_y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)
```

Now, I convert the words in `x_train` to numerical data using TfidfVectorizer:

```
tfidfvectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words='en')
x_traincv = tfidfvectorizer.fit_transform(x_train.astype('U'))
```

Now, I convert `x_traincv` to an array:

```
a = x_traincv.toarray()
```

I also convert `x_testcv` to a numerical array:

```
x_testcv=tfidfvectorizer.fit_transform(x_test)
x_testcv = x_testcv.toarray()
```

Now, I have

```
mnb = MultinomialNB()
b=np.array(y_test)
error_score = 0
b=np.array(y_test)
for i in range(len(x_test)):
    mnb.fit(x_testcv,y_test)
    testmessage=x_test.iloc[i]
    predictions = mnb.predict(x_testcv[i].reshape(1,-1))
    error_score = error_score + (predictions-int(b[i]))**2
    print(testmessage)
    print(predictions)
print(error_score/len(x_test))
```

However, an example of the results I get are:

> Bring it back
> [0]
> It is greatly appreciatd when
> [0]
> Apologies in advance
> [0]
> Can you please
> [0]
> See you then
> [0]
> I hope this email finds you well.
> [0]
> Thanks in advance
> [0]
> I am sorry to inform
> [0]
> You’re absolutely right
> [0]
> I am deeply regretful
> [0]
> Shoot me through
> [0]
> I’m looking forward to
> [0]
> As I already stated
> [0]
> Hello
> [0]
> We expect all students
> [0]
> If it’s not too late
> [0]

and this repeats on a large scale, even for phrases that are obviously very angry. When I removed all data containing a '0' from the .csv file, the now modal value (a 10) is the only prediction for my sentences.

Why is this happening? Is it some weird way to minimise error? Are there any inherent flaws in my code? Should I take a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, you are fitting The MultinomialNB with the test set. In your loop you have `mnb.fit(x_testcv,y_test)` but you should do `mnb.fit(x_traincv,y_train)`

Second, when performing pre-processing you should call the `fit_transform` only on the training data while on the test you should call only the `transform` method.

Comment: Hey Francesco, thanks for your answer. The second recommendation worked, but the first one didn't. When I don't fit the test data, it comes up with an error which says, "ValueError: X has 59 features, but MultinomialNB is expecting 62 features as input."

Comment: Weird, the error says that your train and test set have a different number of features.
Try moving the fit outside the loop
```
mnb.fit(x_traincv,y_train)
for i in range(len(x_test))):
    ...
```
But anyway, even for future reference, you should **never** use your test data to train a ML model, it is fundamental error which may and will invalidate any result you obtain.